# Taking the HOG descriptor of an image using HOGDescriptor from EMGU CV C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, pattern-recognition

How can I compute the hog descriptor vector of an image using EMGU CV and C#.

If i make something like this:

```
float[] f;
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(fullPath);

f = hog.Compute(img1, Size.Empty, Size.Empty,null );
```

it doesn't work, it gives a

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

exception. I want to compute the hog descriptor with default parameters.

Does someone know how to do this ?

Emgu cv is very poorly documented.

I have modified the code and now I am getting the following error: "External component has thrown an exception" The code is listed below

```
public float[] GetVector(Image<Bgr, Byte> im)
    {
        HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor();    // with defaults values
       // Image<Bgr, Byte> pImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(;
       //pImage.ROI = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(64, 128));
        Point[] p = new Point[im.Width * im.Height];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < im.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < im.Height; j++)
            {
                Point p1 = new Point(i, j);
                p[k++] = p1;
            }
        }
        return hog.Compute(im, new Size(8, 8), new Size(0, 0), p);
    }
```

Comment: On which line exactly? Debug your code and see what is `null`.

Comment: f = hog.Compute(img1, Size.Empty, Size.Empty,null ); on this one; they say in the function documentation that if you don't need the locations for computation you can let it null. I don't need locations I want to compute the hog descriptor for all the image not just portions(some locations)

Comment: Just for the record - I have seen a problem similar with this one on stack overflow, but no one was able to solve it. EMGU  CV is very poorly documented

Comment: I have modified the code and now I am getting the following error: "External component has thrown an exception" The code is listed below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for the record here is he answer:

```
public Image<Bgr, Byte> Resize(Image<Bgr, Byte> im)
        {
            return im.Resize(64, 128, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);
        }
        public float[] GetVector(Image<Bgr, Byte> im)
        {
            HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor();    // with defaults values
            Image<Bgr, Byte> imageOfInterest = Resize(im);
            Point[] p = new Point[imageOfInterest.Width * imageOfInterest.Height];
            int k = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < imageOfInterest.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < imageOfInterest.Height; j++)
                {
                    Point p1 = new Point(i, j);
                    p[k++] = p1;
                }
            }

            return hog.Compute(imageOfInterest, new Size(8, 8), new Size(0, 0), p);
        }
```

If someone else will ever need it  :)

Comment: Why the Resize should be always width less than height?

Comment: @HazemAbdullah pretty old comment, but I'll answer just in case someone asks himself the same. This dimension was used in the paper and was suggested by the authors as their primary aim with this type of detection was to obtain better results on the task of pedestrian detection, check "Histograms of oriented gradients for human detection" paper for further details.