# Hog descriptor emgu cv

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, emgucv

I'm working on a project with Kinect Sensor and Emgu CV.
I'm taking the person detected into a rectangle and divide it into smaller pieces. I send each piece into Emgu CV's HoG fuction and I'm waiting for a float array as a result for each sent piece.

Problem is when I send an Image into my HoG function, program exits without warnin/exception on Compute method.

My Hog function is: (taken from: [Taking the HOG descriptor of an image using HOGDescriptor from EMGU CV C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497798/taking-the-hog-descriptor-of-an-image-using-hogdescriptor-from-emgu-cv-c-sharp))

```
    public Image<Bgr, Byte> Resize(Image<Bgr, Byte> im)
    {
        return im.Resize(64, 128, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    }
    public float[] GetVector(Image<Bgr, Byte> im)
    {
        HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor();    // with defaults values
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imageOfInterest = Resize(im);
        System.Drawing.Point[] p = new System.Drawing.Point[imageOfInterest.Width * imageOfInterest.Height];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < imageOfInterest.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < imageOfInterest.Height; j++)
            {
                System.Drawing.Point p1 = new System.Drawing.Point(i, j);
                p[k++] = p1;
            }
        }
        float[] result = hog.Compute(imageOfInterest, new System.Drawing.Size(16, 16), new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0), p);
        return result;
    }
```

I tried to catch a dump with Procdump but its exiting without catching anything when my program crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem myself.

If you try to send the p array into Compute function it gives error.

You can solve this by sending a null array instead of p[]

```
        float[] result = hog.Compute(imageOfInterest, new System.Drawing.Size(16, 16), new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0), NULL ARRAY HERE);
```